# .rangeOfString() with switch in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, switch-statement

I want to check if my input has a rangeOfString must with a lot of different strings to check.

basically this if statement but using a switch to check a big list of different strings

```
if (input.rangeOfString("lol") != nil) {
    println("yes")
}
```

I've tried doing this but it isn't working.

```
switch input {
case rangeOfString("lol"):
    println("lol")
case rangeOfString("dw"):
    println("dw")
default:
    println("Default")
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While the others answers are probably right about `if` being a better way to go, you can do something like this via heroic abuse of the `~=` operator:

```
import Foundation

struct Substring {
    let substr: String
    init(_ substr: String) { self.substr = substr }
}

func ~=(substr: Substring, str: String) -> Bool {
    return str.rangeOfString(substr.substr) != nil
}

let input = "contains wat"

switch input {
case Substring("lol"), Substring("wat"):
    println("huh?")   // this one is picked
case Substring("dw"):
    println("dw")
// you can also mix and match
case "Explicit full string":
    println("matches whole string")
default:
    println("Default")
}
```

Switch statements in Swift can be extended via overloading of the `~=` operator.  So for example, the reason this works:

```
switch 2.5 {
case 0...5: println("between nought and five")
default:    println("not in range")
}
```

is because there is a definition of the `~=` operator that matches any kind of `Comparable` type to an interval:

```
func ~=<I : IntervalType>(pattern: I, value: I.Bound) -> Bool
```

Here, by creating a new type of `Substring`, I've created a way to match strings to substrings.

In theory you could skip the creation of the `Substring` type and do the following:

```
func ~=(substr: String, str: String) -> Bool {
    return str.rangeOfString(str) != nil
}

let input = "contains lol"

switch input {
case "lol":
    println("lol")
case "dw":
    println("dw")
default:
    println("Default")
}
```

This would work, but would be a *bad idea* because now you'll have changed the way switches on strings work universally so that partial matches are always true, which could lead to some unpleasant and unexpected behaviour elsewhere in your code.

Comment: Love this. Still will be very verbose with 50 different cases in the switch. I'd prefer a loop iterating over an array :D

Comment: agreed, but I felt a little bad that the question was getting slapped down quite so hard, since it can be done...

Comment: @Airspeed Velocity this seems promising! could you explain a bit more about struct, subset and ~= as they are completely new to me. I'm also reading the relevant pages from the iOS Developer Library as we speak

Comment: From what I understand this would also give me the option of doing something different at every case instead of the same things at every "word". which is a plus!

Comment: Yes, that's right, you could match multiple strings.  Have edited to demonstrate.

Comment: @AirspeedVelocity I'm having some trouble making it work. If I change the input to `"dw"` it still prints `"huh?"`

Comment: @user3199999 oops sorry there was a typo in my original - fixed now

Comment: `rangeOfString:` doesn't return `nil`, guys.  Check `location` for `NSNotFound`.

Comment: @Hyperbole check again

Comment: @AirspeedVelocity I did. https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Reference/Swift_String_Structure/index.html#//apple_ref/swift/struct/s:SS doesn't even have that method documented, so are you bridging to `NSString#rangeOfString:` automatically? If not, can you link to the doc that shows the prototype for `String#rangeOfString`?

Comment: @Hyperbole type `import Foundation` into a playground and command-click `Foundation`. You’ll see several additional methods that are not part of the standard library, including an extension to `String` that provides `rangeOfString`, and which returns a `Range<Int>?`.

Comment: This is brilliant! Had a long, very clear, switch/case statement which I thought I was going to have to throw away because I needed one case to match a substring, and the rest to match against a full string.

Answer (score 6):

You misunderstood the idea of a `switch` statement. It checks the value of one expression against multiple possible values, and optionally lets you access associated values of an enumeration. It *does not* let you pass a single value to multiple expressions listed as switch cases<sup>*</sup>, and pick whichever provides the first match.

You need to make a chain of `if`-`else`s to make your code work:

```
if (input.rangeOfString("lol") != nil) {
    println("lol")
} else if (input.rangeOfString("dw") != nil) {
    println("dw")
} else {
    println("Default")
}
```

> I would like to check if a word is being used in the input and I have like 50 words I'd like to check.

Then the `switch` is not a good alternative either. Make a container of the words you wish to search, and use `filter` to find all matches:

```
let input = "hahalolblah"
let words = ["lol", "blah", "hello"];
let matches = words.filter {input.rangeOfString($0) != nil}
println(matches) // Produces [lol, blah]
```

<sup>*</sup> It turns out that `switch` lets you pass one expression to an override of the `~=` operator, along with values coming from `case`s of the `switch`. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29609457/335858) for details.

Comment: I thought this was the case too but wasn't sure.

Comment: Wow that seems like a really complicated way to do this.

Comment: If I would like to check if a word is being used in the input and I have like 50 words I'd like to check. that if-else statement will be crazy big

Comment: "It does not let you pass a single value to multiple expressions, and pick whichever provides the first match."  In fairness, in Swift, it kind of does, so long as you couch those expressions in the form of values of some kind... Swift switches are very flexible.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do something like:

```
switch true {
case myString.rangeOfString("lol") != nil: 
    print("lol");
case myString.rangeOfString("dw") != nil: 
    print("dw");
default:
    print("Default")
}
```